# Организация разработки + git

Tags: битрикс, git

Никогда до этого не пользовался гитом поэтому пишу тут. Есть несколько проектов на битриксе и их необходимо поддерживать. У битрикса есть папка local в которой лежит наш кастомный код. Не хочется разворачивать виртуалхосты для каждого проекта, тем более что различаются они только одной папкой local.

Каким образом проще организовать разработку при таких условиях? Могу я подключить к одной папке несколько репозиториев и затем выбирать какой использовать?

Comment: может держать код для каждого битрикса в отдельной ветке? Тогда буквально одной (ну иногда двумя-тремя) командами можно переключиться с одной ветки на другую и работать с другим битриксом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вам подойдут ветки (branches) гита. Начиная с какого-то общего состояния кода можно создать по ветке на каждый проект. Можно вносить изменения в ветку, переключаться между ветками, сохраняя состояния в пределах веток, будет возможность переносить изменения между ветками

Ветки можно создать командой

```
git checkout -b project1
```

Сохранять изменения в текущую ветку

```
git commit
```

Выложить изменения в удаленный репозиторий

```
git push
```

Переключаться между ветками

```
git checkout project1
```

Переносить отдельные коммиты между ветками (проектами)

```
git cherry-pick asdfs
```

где asdfs - первые символы хэша коммита (указанный коммит будет перенесен в текущую ветку)

При этом сервер production можно также переключить на конкретную ветку и команда

```
git pull
```

будет забирать из удаленного репозитория изменения на этой ветке

Что касается разных репозиториев, то гит их поддерживает, но мне кажется в текущую задачу они не вписываются, т.к. там задача обратная - один и тот же код в разных репозиториях

Comment: Если к каждому бранчу добавить ветку dev, в если ещё и на каждого разработчика свою, а проектов станет штук 50, то в подобной структуре будет очень легко запутаться. Я прав?

Comment: я работал в проекте, в котором было около 1000 активных веток. Если выработать соглашения по именованию и раздать соответствующие права, то ошибок не будет. например, ветку dev назвать project1_dev. Но я соглашусь, что мой вариант не без минусов

Comment: в git большое кол-во веток - нормальное состояние. 

В каждом проекте можно ещё добавить файл readme,  в котором писать, что это за проект, для кого он нужен и тому подобное.